# Append a list that’s in another list

Tags: python

I’m trying to append a list that’s in another list.

```
import random
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = [list1, list2]

Index = random.choice(list3)
Index = list3.index(Index)
print(Index)
list3[Index].append(“Test”)
print(list3[Index])
```

I want it to add “test” to either list1 or list2 depending on the value of index.

For some reason, if I repeat the process twice, and the value of index changes, “Test” is added twice to the same list. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Does that code runs?

Comment: It runs, but it doesn’t accomplish what I want.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? It gives me TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list on Python 3.5

Comment: I’m using 3.6. I find it’s best

Comment: This code doesn't run. Your 'index' variable is not an int, so it can't be used in the list3[index]

Comment: Ok. So we can just use .index() to get a variable

Comment: @SanguineL Index will always be 0. Both list1 and list2 are blank lists, so when you look for the index of a blank list in list3, you will always return 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`random.choice` returns one of the items in the given list, which in this case are the references to, rather than the indices of, `list1` and `list2`.

You should append directly to the list returned by `random.choice` instead:

```
import random
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = [list1, list2]

lst= random.choice(list3)
lst.append('Test')
print(list3)
```

This can output:

```
[['Test'], []]
```

Comment: Yeah. It said I had to wait 4 minutes. I got it now.